# unicode codepoint from python to java

Tags: java, python-2.7, unicode

I had python read a bunch of unicode text and then save some of them to a file then later use java to read it.
For example: `Ờ` is read as `u'\xe1\xbb\x9c'` by python.
when my java program read the file, the character is displayed as 3 different characters `á»` (the last one just doesn't show here) which I assumed to be `\xe1, \xbb, \x9c` respectively, How do I make java to display the character properly?

Comment: Read the file using [StandardCharsets.UTF_8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html#UTF_8).

Comment: `InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`

I just tried using this but it doesn't work

Comment: Are you double-encoding the output in your python code? `'\xe1\xbb\x9c'` would be written to the file as `'\xc3\xa1\xc2\xbb\xc2\x9c'` if it was encoded again.